# SQL JOIN, GROUP BY, DATES

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables and I have trouble with the quantity. I will apply my solution down. SUM and GROUP BY are not working.

PRODUCT_INFORMATION

```
PRODUCT_ID  
PRODUCT_NAME  
PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION  
PCATEGORY_ID  
PRODUCT_STATUS  
WARRANTY_PERIOD
```

ORDERS

```
ORDER_ID  
ORDER_DATE  
ORDER_MODE  
CUSTOMER_ID  
ORDER_STATUS  
ORDER_TOTAL
```

ORDER_ITEMS

```
ORDER_ID   
LINE_ITEM_ID  
PRODUCT_ID
UNIT_PRICE  
QUANTITY
```

• whose name (PRODUCT_NAME) does not contain the characters ‘_’ and ‘<’.

• the total number of products sold (QUANTITY column of table oe.ORDER_ITEMS) of a given type to be greater than 200.

The list should contain the following columns:

• PRODUCT_NAME (by oe.PRODUCT_INFORMATION)

• TOTAL_QUANTITY - the total number of products sold of a given type

```
SELECT p.PRODUCT_NAME, sum(oi.QUANTITY), p.WARRANTY_PERIOD AS WARRANTY, o.ORDER_MODE
FROM PRODUCT_INFORMATION p 
    LEFT JOIN ORDER_ITEMS oi ON p.PRODUCT_ID=oi.PRODUCT_ID
    LEFT JOIN ORDERS o ON o.ORDER_ID = oi.ORDER_ID
WHERE (p.PRODUCT_NAME NOT LIKE '%<%' 
AND p.PRODUCT_NAME NOT LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\')
AND oi.QUANTITY>200
group by p.PRODUCT_NAME;
```

Comment: Oracle and mysql are two different database products. Which one do you use?

Comment: defining well the RDBMS helps, plus providing some dummy data and an expected result from the query :)

Answer (score 2):

What does "... are not working" mean? Did you get any error? If so, which one?

---

What is obvious, is that `GROUP BY` clause has to contain all non-aggregated columns. As problem doesn't require them to be displayed, I **removed** them from the `select` column list (both `p.WARRANTY_PERIOD` and `o.ORDER_MODE`).

Furthermore, you should move the "`quantity > 200`" condition from `WHERE` into the `HAVING` clause.

Finally, in order to avoid characters to be *escaped*, I switched from `NOT LIKE` to `INSTR`.

Something like this:

```
  SELECT p.product_name, 
         SUM (oi.quantity) sum_quantity
    FROM product_information p
         LEFT JOIN order_items oi ON p.product_id = oi.product_id
         LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
   WHERE INSTR (p.product_name, '<') = 0
     AND INSTR (p.product_name, '_') = 0
GROUP BY p.product_name
  HAVING SUM (oi.quantity) > 200;
```

Comment: But if I want to add and  p.WARRANTY_PERIOD AS WARRANTY, o.ORDER_MODE shoul I add them to GROUP BY?

Comment: Yes, you should (as I said: "GROUP BY clause has to contain all non-aggregated columns").

Answer (score 1):

Your query selects columns which are not in the GROUP BY clause, which is usually not a problem with MySQL, but would be with any other vendor.

Since you don't require the two last columns in your output, I suggest you just get rid of them.

Also, MySQL supports [regexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html), which are more suited to your problem than LIKE in my opinion.

```
SELECT p.PRODUCT_NAME, SUM(oi.QUANTITY)
FROM PRODUCT_INFORMATION p 
LEFT JOIN ORDER_ITEMS oi ON p.PRODUCT_ID=oi.PRODUCT_ID
LEFT JOIN ORDERS o ON o.ORDER_ID = oi.ORDER_ID
WHERE p.PRODUCT_NAME REGEXP '[_<]' = 0
GROUP BY p.PRODUCT_NAME
HAVING SUM(oi.QUANTITY) > 200;
```

Edit : As pointed out by @Littlefoot, the quantity condition should be tested after the grouping and not before, and should therefore be in the HAVING clause rather than in the WHERE clause.